# how to install package in jupyter notebook for only one session in Anaconda

Tags: python, installation, package

Is it possible to install package for only one session using Anaconda?
I tried to use

```
! pip install package
```

in jupyter notebook in Anaconda, but it was installed to the directory under original base environment.
I don't want to change my original base since it will failed my update of anaconda navigator.
I don't want to install package in a special virtual environment either.
I just need the package is available for just one session, that means everytime I close the notebook, the package will be removed. Is it possible?
I know in Google Colab, this is feasible. But I want to know is this possible in local Anaconda? Thanks.

Comment: Lots to unpack here. It is feasible in Google Colab because it is a temporary session in a virtual system they give you. Once it expires it is gone. Essentially it is a special virtual environment. You've rejected that as an option though in your text. You could install docker locally make a container to run Jupyter in and install the additional package in that. If you don't save new container image with docker commit then next time you run the container, it will be like that didn't happen. However, Anaconda has a way to make environments to allow you to not mess up the base environment...

Comment: <continued> You can easily make an environment and try something and get rid of it. Other important things: (1) As you have chosen to use Anaconda/conda as your **primary** package manager, you should avoid using `pip`. The only exception if packages that don't have a conda recipe. (2) You should not be using an exclamation point in conjunction with a `pip` or `conda` install command in modern Jupyter. In 2019 the magic install command was added to insure the installation run in an active Jupyter `.ipynb` file occurs in the environment where the kernel is running. The exclamation point ...

Comment: <continued> does not do this and that is why the magic variations were added. You should be using `%pip install <package>`. See more about the modern `%pip install` command [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

Comment: By the way, you can get conda on a temporary virtual machine by going [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/conda) and pressing 'launch binder'. Then you can install whatever in the session with `%conda install` and it will be gone when you launch again later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and suggestions, learned a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `!`. Instead use `%` so the new code should look like `%pip install package_name`.

This will install the package in the current environment instead of the global environment.